# textbox value does not pass to javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript, html, textbox, passwords

I have this codes, they should be passing the value of the vercode but unfortunately its not doing it... I want it to pass the code from the textbox to javascript and to the php

Here is the code:

### HTML:

```
    <?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
    <title>Adviser Registration</title>
    <head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/ico" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function upperCase()
        {
            //get ids
            var lname=document.getElementById("lname");
            var fname=document.getElementById("fname");
            var mname=document.getElementById("mname");
            //function
            lname.value=lname.value.toUpperCase();
            fname.value=fname.value.toUpperCase();
            mname.value=mname.value.toUpperCase();
        }
    </script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="js/gen_validatorv31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reg.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapheader">
    </div>
    <div id="wrap">
        <table width="902"  class="tableaccountinfo2" style="border-collapse:collapse; background:url(images/dock-bg.gif)">
            <tr>
                <td width="39" class="picaccount2"></td>
                <td width="851" height="33">Account Info</td>
            </tr>
        </table>


      <table width="898">  
        <tr>
                <td width="30"></td>
                <td width="856" style="color:#060; font-size:12px;"><b>*Note:</b>Please make sure that your account information is a registered email address. This will be used as your Autumn Account and for account validation. </td>
            </tr>
       </table>



        <table width="928" align="center" id="tablereg" style="border-collapse:collapse; font-size:14px;">
             <tr>
                <td height="23">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="137" height="44">E-mail Address:</td>
      <td width="242"><input type="text" id="email" /></td>
                <td width="505"><span id="email_feedback">&nbsp;</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="44">Password:</td>
              <td><input type="password" id="pass" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="44">Repeat Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" id="rpass" /></td>
                <td><span id="pass_av">&nbsp;</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
      </table>
      <table id="tablereg" style="width:400px;border-collapse:collapse;font-size:14px;">
             <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="137">Verification Code: </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" id="vercode" name="vercode" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
      </table>


     <!----------------------Personal Info------------------------>
    <table width="902"  class="tableaccountinfo" style="border-collapse:collapse; background:url(images/dock-bg.gif)"  >
            <tr>
            <td width="36" class="picpersonal"></td>
                <td width="854" height="33">
                    Personal Information
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="899" align="center" id="tablereg" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
             <tr>
                <td height="23">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="123" height="44">Firstname:</td>
                <td width="765"><input type="text" id="fname" onChange="upperCase()" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="44">Middle Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="mname" onChange="upperCase()" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="44">Lastname:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="lname" onChange="upperCase()" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
      </table>

       <!----------------------School Info------------------------>

<table width="902"  class="tableaccountinfo" style="border-collapse:collapse; background:url(images/dock-bg.gif)">
            <tr>
             <td width="37" class="picstudentinfo">  </td>
                <td width="853" height="33">
                    School Information
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table style="border-collapse:collapse;" align="center" id="tablereg">
             <tr>
                <td height="23" width="125px">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="44" width="125px">Staff ID:</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="staffid" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="44" width="125px">College:</td>
                            <td>
                                <select id="college">
                                <option value="please_select">Select your college...</option>
                                <?php
                                include "connection.php";
                                $getcollege = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM college");
                                while($collrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($getcollege))
                                {
                                    $coll = $collrow['collegeab'];
                                    $collid = $collrow['college_id'];
                                ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $collid; ?>"><?php echo $coll; ?></option>
                                <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                                </select>
                            </td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td height="44" width="125px">Coordinator:</td>
                <td id="coorhold">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td height="23" width="125px">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
      </table>

       <!----------------------Incase you forgot your password------------------------>

     <table width="902"  class="tableaccountinfo" style="border-collapse:collapse; background:url(images/dock-bg.gif)">
            <tr>
                <td width="37" class="picincase"></td>
                <td width="853" height="33">
                    In case you forgot your password
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


      <!----------------------Registration Result------------------------>

     <table width="928px"  id="tablereg" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td><span id="regresult">&nbsp;</span></td>
        </tr>
     </table>

     <!----------------------Register Button---------------------->

     <table width="928"  id="tablereg" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td width="224"></td>
            <td width="664"><input type="button" id="submitregister" value="Register" name="submitregister" /></td>
        </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/advreg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/chooseadv.js"></script>
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>
function refreshCaptcha()
{
    var img = document.images['captchaimg'];
    img.src = img.src.substring(0,img.src.lastIndexOf("?"))+"?rand="+Math.random()*1000;
}
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

### JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('#submitregister').click(function() {  
    //grab values
    var vercode = $('#vercode').val();

    //show loading text
    $('#regresult').text('Loading...');

    //perform http request
    $.post('validations/vadvreg.php', { vercode: vercode
    }, function(data){
        $('#regresult').html(data);
    });
});
```

---

### PHP

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['vercode'])){

    $vercode = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['vercode']));

}else {
    echo "<font color='red'>Please fill in ALL fields!</font>1";
}
?>
```

---

Comment: This is not relevant to your problem, but please take note that `mysql_` functions are deprecated.

Comment: Try changing your input to read <input type="password" id="vercode" name="vercode" />

Comment: @twoleggedhorse i've tried it, didn't worked

Comment: It is inside a <form>? Please show the entire form section of the html...

Comment: Try putting an alert(vercode); after the live var vercode... Is it displaying the value? Also have a look to see if the request is being fired by using the developer tools - hit F12 and use the network tools or use www.fiddler2.com - the URL might be unresolved

Comment: okay wait for a while I'll try that

Comment: sorry guys I didn't know what I do, it seems to be working now and I didn't know what I do xD

Comment: Could have been the browser caching the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Inputs must have the `name` attribute in order to be sent as part of the request when the form is submitted:

```
<input type=password id=vercode name=vercode>
```

From the W3C: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#attr-fe-name

Comment: I get the value of vercode through its ID, not by name, I am not using forms, I use javascript to get the value

Comment: @jekuyotcosta what do you expect to happen exactly?  You didn't really say what the problem was, just that "it's not doing it"

Comment: the problem is it's not passing the value of the textbox with the ID vercode

Comment: @jekuyotcosta how do you know that?  Is it passing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Use the done command as specified in jQuery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
//perform http request
$.post('validations/vadvreg.php', { vercode: vercode})
.done(function(data){
    $('#regresult').html(data);
});
```

Comment: Ensure the path is correct. If the file resides in the same directory then vadvref.php would service.